# Most allowed Taxonomies in Appearance->Menus

Tags: menus, terms

I am managing a large list(300) of "places" taxonomies, and I need to create a menu with those places. the WordPress menu system seems like the way to go but when I save the menu I am getting a PHP timeout error.

Why is this taking so long to save the menu? Is there a recommended limit for the amount of terms you should be adding to a menu?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the menu system is great, it *is* a little intensive; 300 is obviously pushing it.

Would a code snippet not be the way to go?

```
<ul class="places">
    <?php wp_list_categories( 'taxonomy=places&title_li=' ) ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: the problem with that solution is that I need the customization afforded by using the Menu GUI. Hopefully this gets resolved in an upcoming version of WP